# How can I stop this text from folding down in a fixed width layout?

Tags: css, fixed-width

I have this site set to fixed-width, but the info block (to the right) keeps folding down, causing it to appear beneath the footer when I shrink the browser window or view it in mobile
http://royalstudiosla.com/videos/zedd-ft-foxes-clarity-acoustic/

```
    <article id="singlevideo">
        <div id="video">
        </div>
        <div id="info">


        </div>

</article>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to set a fixed width on the wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly but I think you mean 'Word break':

```
 p.test {word-break:break-all;}

 Options:
 normal :   Break words according to their usual rules
 break-all  : Lines may break between any two letters
```

Or I'm misunderstanding and you want to Allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line.
In that case use:

```
 p.test {word-wrap:break-word;}

 Options:
 normal :   Break words only at allowed break points
 break-word :   Allows unbreakable words to be broken
```